# Search Keyword Query Language (KQL) has syntax error for date range

Tags: search, keywordquery

I have changed our search query using JavaScript and due to other requirements we now use the 'a' parameter which works fine for just about everything except for a certain date range value.

The following **works** [Any date after YYYY/MM/DD]

```
write:2013/05/20..
//Encoded as
a=write%3A2013%2F05%2F20..
```

The following **does not work** [Any date before YYYY/MM/DD]

```
write:..2013/05/20
//Encoded as
a=write%3A..2013%2F05%2F20
```

I have checked ULS and the error is because the date range wildcard '..' is unexpected

***exact exception* Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryMalformedException: parsekw: QTF_ParseKW: Unexpected Token - .. at postion: 32**

Comment: I have also tried using quotes & using the '=' in place of ':' so far none have worked

Comment: If this is like other wildcard in SharePoints search, only prefix matching is supported

Comment: The default OOB refinement panel passes the same date range value as I use, just with the 'r' parameter. I guess for the time being I will just set the range A..B where A is some value older than the system & a special case instead of the proper ..B format